# Laravel 5.0 Auth uses Homestead instead of .env DB

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, authentication, pdo

I've setup Laravel 5.0 (that's a requirement) and set it up to use remote MySQL DB. All migrations and data interactions pass OK, but when trying to use Auth login POST, it fails with `PDOException` in `Connector.php` line 47:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory, mentioning " PDO->__construct('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=homestead', 'homestead', 'secret', array('0', '2', '0', false, false))"

WHERE did it take that homestead DSN? Why does it skip the `database.php` config and `.env` config? If I try to add to `.env` some socket info (well it should not count here, right?) the socket path passes to the mentioned `PDOException` call stack, but hostname, login etc. NOT!

Confused. What am I doing wrong?

**UPD**
Here's the .env:

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=SomeRandomString

DB_HOST=mysql.someremteohosting.net
DB_DATABASE=mydb
DB_USERNAME=myuser
DB_PASSWORD=mysuperpassword

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync
```

And here's database.php:

```
<?php

return [
    'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_CLASS,    
    'default' => 'mysql',    
    'connections' => [    
        'sqlite' => [
            'driver'   => 'sqlite',
            'database' => storage_path().'/database.sqlite',
            'prefix'   => '',
        ],

        'mysql' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
        ],

        'pgsql' => [
            'driver'   => 'pgsql',
            'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'  => 'utf8',
            'prefix'   => '',
            'schema'   => 'public',
        ],

        'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',
            'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'prefix'   => '',
        ],

    ],

    'migrations' => 'migrations',    
    ],

];
```

Again, all migrations work. I can create, save and fetch objects in tinker without any problem. The only reference to homestead is in .env.example file.

Comment: `grep -R homestead *` from the project directory, it should show you where it is. I'm guessing that it would be in `config/homestead/database.php`. Also double-check the config settings in `.env` to make sure they're correct.

Comment: Could you post your .env and database.php config?

Comment: Sorry for long wait - had to sleep at might :-) Updated the question with the answers to your questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what exactly was wrong here. The only place where I found `'homestead'` in the app code was in `.env.example`. I deleted it an ran `composer dump-autoload`. After that it worked. Still surprised about laravel lurking into .example config without any reason.

Comment: Simply restarting the server worked for me. I guess same was the issue with you and not the .env-example file.